# Alleged miscarriage of justice, later proven guilty

Tags: criminal-law

I'm looking for examples of cases where there have been alleged miscarriages of justice, but subsequent research/appeals have turned up more evidence of *guilt* rather than *innocence*.

The only example I've found so far is that of James Hanratty, aka the A6 Murderer. Executed for murder in 1962, attracted a long running campaign to have the verdict overturned and be given posthumous pardon. Eventually a campaign by his family resulted in his body being exhumed and DNA samples being compared with those found on the victim proving guilt beyond reasonable doubt.

Are there any other similar cases?

UPDATE - I'm looking for those cases where new evidence was found that added a final nail to the coffin, rather than those case where new evidence exonerates the wrongfully convicted. I'm also interested in those cases that became a fashionable *cause célèbre* rather than those largely limited to family and close friends. The Hanratty case attracted a lot of celebrity interest for nearly 40 years before the family demanded an exhumation and DNA testing - which proved beyond doubt that he was guilty. (interestingly, the family are still claiming that he's innocent)

Comment: Aren't all people who appeal convictions "alleging a miscarriage of justice"?

Comment: I think you are interested in claims of actual innocence: but legal appeals are based on supposed procedural errors. If the nature of the legal appeal (e.g. ineffective representation) *isn't* what's at issue, then this really is not a legal question – it's closer to a political question, or maybe a skeptics question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a question about law, it is a question about true crime history. I'm not sure where it belongs, but it doesn't have a legal answer.